# Implementing as conversions in swift

Tags: swift

I'm making a class that is similar to CLLocation and I wanted to be able o do:

```
customClass as! CLLocaiton
```

Do I need to implement any special protocols or anything like that?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *cast* from CustomClass to CLLocation, because they are not related to one another. Thus, you won't be able to do it that way at all; you have no power over how the `as` operator works (you cannot customize its behavior).

You can, however, *coerce* from CustomClass to CLLocation, in just the same way as you would write e.g. `Double(myInteger)`. What you need to do, in other words, is to write an extension to CLLocation that implements `init(customClass:CustomClass)`. Thus you'll be able to hand an instance of your CustomClass over to this initializer and get back a new CLLocation instance based upon it.

So, let's pretend you custom class is something like this:

```
class CustomClass {
    var lat : Double = 0
    var long : Double = 0
}
```

Then you could extend CLLocation like this:

```
extension CLLocation {
    convenience init(_ cc:CustomClass) {
        self.init(latitude:cc.lat, longitude:cc.long)
    }
}
```

And now you can make a CustomClass instance like this:

```
let cc = CustomClass()
cc.lat = 30
cc.long = 40
```

And later you can coerce it to a CLLocation like this:

```
let loc = CLLocation(cc) // ta-daa!
```

Thus you are talking just the way you would talk with `Double(myInteger)`.

---

Alternatively, just write a method in CustomClass that returns an "equivalent" CLLocation. This approach is probably easier. So, let's pretend your class is something like this:

```
class CustomClass {
    var lat : Double = 0
    var long : Double = 0
    func location() -> CLLocation {
        return CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    }
}
```

So now you can work with an instance of your CustomClass:

```
let cc = CustomClass()
cc.lat = 30
cc.long = 40
```

And then later you can "convert" it to a CLLocation:

```
let loc = cc.location()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to do anything special. Just make `CustomClass` a subclass of `CLLocation` and it will be implicitly *upcast* any time it is needed. Upcasting with the `as` keyword should also work.

```
class CustomClass: CLLocation {}

let customLocation = CustomClass()

let upcastCustomLocation = customLocation as CLLocation
```

If for some reason you are not able or willing to make `CustomClass` a relative of `CLLocation` through inheritance, you will not be able to use the `as` keyword (as pointed out by matt).

Answer (score 0):

The `as`/`as!`/`as?` family of operators is not for *conversion* of one type to another; it's for *casting*.

Casting is when you tell the compiler that a value of one type can be safely interpreted as a value of another type. In Swift, this specifically (due to the "safe" part) means types that are related in the type hierarchy — subtypes and supertypes. If you have a `SomeClass` type, and a `SomeSubclass` type that extends it, or a `SomeProtocol` type and a `SomeType` (class, struct, or enum) that adopts that protocol, you can always safely upcast from the more specific type to the more general type (the superclass or protocol) with the `as` operator. And you can downcast a general type to a more specific type with the `as!` or `as?` operator — those involve some possibility of failure because the compiler can't know if you're going down the right branch of the type hierarchy.

If you have types that *aren't* related through the type hierarchy (that is, one is not a subclass of the other, or one is not a protocol adopted by the other), you can't cast. Instead, you *convert*.

In Swift, conversion is (almost) always explicit — you create a value of the converted-to type using one of its initializers that takes a value of the converted-from type. Examples:

```
// convert numeric types
let one: Int = 1
let onePointOh = Float(one) 
// convert a sequence to an array
let oneToTen = Array(1...10)
```

So, if you're writing a class that's *like* `CLLocation`, but isn't actually a subclass of `CLLocation`, and you want to use it in a context that requires a `CLLocation` instance, you need to create the way to get a `CLLocation` instance from your class.

You could do that with a method or computed property:

```
extension MyLocationClass {
    var asCLLocation: CLLocation {
        return CLLocation(latitude: self.lat, longitude: self.long)
    }
}
```

Or, if you like the construction/conversion syntax used in the standard library, by extending `CLLocation` to add a convenience initializer based on your class:

```
extension CLLocation {
    convenience init(_: MyLocationClass) {
        self.init(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    }
}
```